# The correct way to reading csv from assets (android, web, win) in flutter or where did I go wrong (works only win)

Tags: flutter, csv, dart

Have a nice day, everyone. I've been trying to figure out how to read a CSV file for two weeks now. I want to consistently achieve the same result for Android, Web and Windows. And I get only Windows: the file is read in its entirety, does not cycling, and is displayed in the Widget.
In the variant for Android and Web, approximately the same thing happens: the file is not read to the end (only the first line), it is re-read again to infinity and is not displayed in the Widget. I tried dozens of options, edited them dozens of times. And nothing happened. Please tell me what is my mistake. I even took completely ready-made options from the WEB and none of them worked for Android and WEB. Or rather, one option worked for some time without displaying the value in the widget, then I erased it and can't remember how it worked. The copy has not been preserved. I would be glad for an answer regarding the correct reading from the RootBundle, since the error is somewhere there. It may be necessary to read byte by byte, convert to UTF-8. How to do it?

```
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:io' show File, Platform;
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';
import 'package:csv/csv_settings_autodetection.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show debugDefaultTargetPlatformOverride, kDebugMode;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:csv/csv.dart' as csv;
import 'package:matrix2d/matrix2d.dart';
import 'dart:convert'; //utf-8 decoder

// toDo: BUILD TYPE (csv Reading Mode):
int csvMode = 2;               // =1 works fine Android and =2 WEB. Not work Win. Windows Stops Here.       ?iOS?
// 1 ANDROID; 2 WEB            // =3 works fine Windows. Not work Android and WEB. Android and WEB Stops Here.           ?iOS?
// 3 WINDOWS                   // in Android csv read cyclically Why?


String file1 = 'assets/jni/sample01.jni';               // Type String
//File notationCsvFile = new File(file1);                     // Type File
   var notationCsvFile = new File('assets/jni/sample01.jni'); // Type File
List<dynamic> csvLst1 = []; // ready CSV List


void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<List<dynamic>> _data = [];
  void _loadCSV(file1) async {
    final _rawData = await rootBundle.loadString(file1);
    var detect = new FirstOccurrenceSettingsDetector(eols: ['\r\n', '\n']); 
    List<List<dynamic>> _listData =        CsvToListConverter(
                                          csvSettingsDetector: detect,
                                          fieldDelimiter: ";",
                                          shouldParseNumbers: false,
                                          allowInvalid: true)
                                          .convert(_rawData);
    setState(() {
      _data = List.from(_listData.transpose); 
      print(_data); 
    });
  }
  // 
  // 
  //
  // 
  @override 
  void initState() {  /
    super.initState();  
  }  // end init state

  List <List<dynamic>> csvToListR = [];  // for method 2
  Future<List<dynamic>> readCsvFeautr1 () async {                     
    var detect = new FirstOccurrenceSettingsDetector(eols: ['\r\n', '\n']); 
    String myData = await rootBundle.loadString(file1, cache: false);  
    Future <List<dynamic>> listRtrn () async{      
      List<List<dynamic>>  csvTable = CsvToListConverter(csvSettingsDetector: detect, fieldDelimiter: ";", shouldParseNumbers: false, allowInvalid: true).convert(myData);
      List csvTableTmp = List.from(csvTable.transpose);  
      setState(() {csvLst1 = csvTableTmp;});
      return csvTableTmp;
    } // end List
    return listRtrn ();   
  } 
  //
  //
  //
  //
  //
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//
    List <List<dynamic>> csvToListR = [];   
//
//
    Future<void> readCsvFeautr3 (notationCsvFile) async {
      List <List> csvToList1 (File notationCsvFile) {  
        csv.CsvToListConverter tempC = new csv.CsvToListConverter(eol: "\r\n", fieldDelimiter: ";");
        List<List<dynamic>> listCreated = tempC.convert(notationCsvFile.readAsStringSync()); 
        print (listCreated); 
        return listCreated;
      }
      setState(() {
        csvToListR = csvToList1(notationCsvFile);
      });
    } 
   
//
//
    List <List> csvToList (String myData) {  
      var detect = new FirstOccurrenceSettingsDetector(eols: ['\r\n', '\n']); 
      csv.CsvToListConverter tempC = new csv.CsvToListConverter(csvSettingsDetector: detect, eol: "\r\n", fieldDelimiter: ";");
      List<List<dynamic>> listCreated = tempC.convert(myData); 
      setState(() {
        csvToListR = listCreated;
        print(csvToListR.transpose);                                      
      });
      return listCreated; 
    }
    Future<void> readCsvFeautr3a (file1) async {  
      String myData = await rootBundle.loadString(file1, cache: false);                                               
    await csvToList (myData);
    } // end readCsvFeautr3a ()  

    if (csvMode == 1) {                               // 1 ANDROID (see beginning of the file)

      _loadCSV(file1);
    } else if (csvMode == 2) {                        // 2 WEB

      readCsvFeautr3a (file1); //CALLING read csv3a

    } else if (csvMode == 3) {                        // 3 WINDOWS
      readCsvFeautr3 (notationCsvFile); 
      csvLst1 = List.from(csvToListR);

    } else {}






    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            body:
            Row(
              children: [

                //Text(_data.toString())

              ],
            )
        ),
      ),
    );

  } //END WIDGET BUILD
} //end class STATE
```

Comment: Works Only this part:

Comment: No Flutter Doctor! No Invalidate Caches! No!No!No! All the other parts of my code works fine! Only reading form rootBundle does not work!

Comment: P.S.: CSV File with BOM or without does not effect.

Comment: Works Only this part: readCsvFeautr3 ()    //toDo: WORKS PERFECT WIN INSIDE WIDGET BUILD, NOT CYCLING! LIST RETURNS FULLY AT ANY PLACE

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: CSV is ANY CSV exported with default delimiter ";" from Excel with MAX Possible EXCEL Column numbers, with 22 STR and MAX Excel's COLS. Symbols in file [a-z, ~ and *].

Comment: Could it be that android doesn't allow my custom extension JNI but only extension known to it CSV ?

Comment: Shortened the code in half.

Comment: I solved: it was my custom extension. Works only with CSV, even you give custom ext. to CSV - will not work. And Invalidate cache. I use files with BOM. Better method, that returns _data. Worked at all three platforms. Thanks.